# Is including the constant of integration necessary when integrating f prime/f double-prime/etc.?

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose we have the integral $
\int f'(x)dx
$.
My calculus textbook (CPM, third edition) supplies the answer as $f(x) + c$, but doesn't it, according to the fundamental theorem of calculus, evaluate simply to $ f(x) $? Isn't adding the constant of integration unnecessary since, as I understand it:

- the purpose of the constant is to account for constant values lost in differentiation
- any constant value that would have been lost when differentiating from $f(x)$ to $f'(x)$ is already contained in $f(x)$, so adding $+C$ is redundant

I understand that the constant could easily be 0, but according to my reasoning, it would always be 0, making its inclusion completely redundant.

So to clarify: Is their inclusion of the constant of integration here unnecessary? (or am I misunderstanding something of the purpose of the constant of integration)

Comment: The notation for the indefinite integral does not specify a single function. It is the set of all functions with the given derivative. So $\int (d/dx)x^2dx = \int 2x dx = x^2 + c$ for all real values of $c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *definite integrals* you do not need the constant:

$$F(b)-F(a) = \int_a^b f(z)dz$$

Why? Because the constant drops out when we take differences as per the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, the indefinite integral is not a differnece, but an anti-derivative:

$$\int f(z)dz = F(z) + C$$

Since $\frac{d}{dx}[F(z)+C] = f(z)\;\forall C \in \mathbb{R}$

The Fundamental Theorem simply states that the definite integral of a function between two points is the difference of *any* antiderivative of that function evaluated at the endpoints.

Comment: I see. The flaw in my reasoning was the silly assumption that $f'(x)$ could only refer to $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ As you pointed out, this is certainly not the case, since $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)+c$ also equals $f'(x)$.

Comment: @mistekko exactly! :)

Comment: As I am fairly new to the world of calculus (and often misperceptive), I am hesitant to point out errors, but it appears to me that your answer uses $F(x)$ when $f(x)$ would be more correct. If $F(x)$ represents the antiderivative function of $f(x)$, then $\int f(x)dx = F(x)+C$. Then, differentiating each side, $\int f'(x)dx = \frac{d}{dx}(F(x)+C)$, which seem to contradict your answer's assertion that $\int f'(x)dx = F(x) + C$.

Comment: @mistekko - i see where the confusion is. I removed the extra $'$ that was confusing things, so $\int f(x) dx = F(x) + C$

Answer (score 0):

Let's try a simple example:
$$ \eqalign{f(x) &= x\cr
            f'(x) &= 1\cr
    \int f'(x)\; dx &= \int 1 \; dx = x + c\cr} $$
Yes, you need the $+c$.

You always need $+c$ for any antiderivative, because $g(x)$ and $g(x) + c$ always have the same derivative.

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that the indefinite integral generally specifies a *family* of functions, what you're hoping for isn't even true if you try and get around that little detail.  For example, if you use the definition

$$\int f(x) \, dx := \int_0^x f(t)\, dt$$

then $\int f'(x) \, dx$ and $f(x)$ will differ by a constant whenever $f(0)$ is something other than zero.

More generally $\int_a^x f'(t) \, dt$ evaluated at $a$ will be zero, and so will be different from $f(a)$ unless $f(a)$ happens to be zero.

Test it out for yourself.  Let $f(x) = 1$ (the constant function), and compare the two expressions.